# ALTER VIEW with entity manager native query results in syntax error

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to alter a view using the entity managers native query support but receive a syntax error despite the fact that the query runs fine within the sql management studio.

**Code**

```
        var queryString = "ALTER VIEW some_view AS SELECT c.* FROM some_table c WHERE snapshot_run_id = :sId";

        var query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString);
        query.setParameter("sId", 5);
        query.executeUpdate();
```

Error is,

> Syntax error near the keyword VIEW

Is it not possible to alter a view using the javax.persistence entity manager or am I missing something?

Comment: View does not support parameters. I guess, your view definition should be ALTER VIEW some_view AS SELECT c.* FROM some_table c

Comment: Since the parameter is a basic type integer I now wrote it directly in the query: `snapshot_run_id = 5` and that did the trick. Thanks a lot!